# How do native speakers read "of the"?

Tags: pronunciation

[Kingdom of the Crystal Skull](https://zh.forvo.com/word/kingdom_of_the_crystal_skull/)

I always can't hear clearly about "of", especially in "of the".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It absolutely depends on accent. As someone with an English West Midlands accent, I pronounce it as *uv*.

No one would ever right like this, but if you wrote literally how it's pronounced where I'm from then it would be written as *Kingdom've the Crystal Skull*.